# Almost sure convergence and i.o. events

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

$X_n$ be a sequence of random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Then $X_n \rightarrow X (a.s.)$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0, P({\omega \in \Omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \epsilon \ i.o.}) = 0$.

$a.s.$ - almost surely, 
$i.o.$ - infinitely often

I am trying to prove the above statement in $\Rightarrow$ direction. From the definition of $a.s.$ convergence,
$P\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \not \rightarrow X(\omega)\} = 0$

i.e., $P\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \not \rightarrow X(\omega)\} = 0$

i.e., $P\{\omega \in \Omega: lim sup |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > 0\} = 0$

i.e., $P\{\omega \in \Omega: \exists \epsilon(\omega) > 0 \ s.t.\ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > 0\} = 0$.

How do I bring $i.o.$ events in the above? My understanding about $i.o.$ is based on $lim sup$ of events. I am unable to connect the events above with $limsup$ of sets.

Any proper direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the following inclusion.
$\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \not \rightarrow X(\omega)\} \subset \bigcup_{m \geq 1}
\{\omega \in \Omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > 1/m \ i.o.\}$
And the use the inequality
$$ P(\cup A_m   ) \leq \sum_{m}P(A_m).$$

Comment: I am having trouble in translating the meaning of i.o.i.o. events to this problem. $A_n \ i.o$ implies the event $lim sup A_n = \cap_{m = 1}^{\infty} \cup_{n = m}^{\infty} A_n$. Could you help me connect your hints with these sets.

Comment: @minion oh okay I see, there is a very intuitive meaning of  i.o. of $A_n$ it counts exactly the $\omega$ that belong to infinitely many $A_k$.

Comment: could you please define $A_n$ whose $limsup$ is what I am interested in.

Comment: @minion $\omega \in  \limsup A_n \Leftrightarrow    $ there are infinite many $k$ such that $  |X_k-X| > \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of convergence, a sequence $a_n$ converges to the limit $L$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$, 
$|a_n - L| \le \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  The latter can't happen if  $|a_n - L| > \epsilon$ i.o.  Thus 
$\{\omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \epsilon \ \text{i.o.}\}$ is disjoint from $\{\omega: X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)\}$.